# Enemy Prefab not shooting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a laser defender game and I need my enemies to shoot as they are moving, however, they are not shooting. I have created a script EnemyShooting where basically wrote that the enemy should shoot but it is not. Can someone please review my code and tell me why the enemies are not shooting?

The image below is the enemyprefab inspector:
[image: Enemy Inspector]}

Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyShooting : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] float EnemyLaserSpeed = 10f;
[SerializeField] float EnemyLaserFireTime;
[SerializeField] GameObject LaserBulletEnemyPreFab;
[SerializeField] int MaxNumberOfHits = 1;
int CurrentNumberOfHits = 0;
Coroutine FireCoroutine;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if(collider.gameObject.tag == "PlayerLaser")
    {
        if(CurrentNumberOfHits < MaxNumberOfHits)
        {
            CurrentNumberOfHits++;
            Destroy(collider.gameObject);
        }
    }
}

void DestroyEnemy()
{
    if(CurrentNumberOfHits >= MaxNumberOfHits)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

private void Fire()
{
    FireCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ShootContinuously());
}

void BecomeVisible()
{
    Fire();
}

IEnumerator ShootContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        GameObject LaserBulletEnemy = Instantiate(LaserBulletEnemyPreFab, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        LaserBulletEnemy.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, EnemyLaserSpeed);
        EnemyLaserFireTime = Random.Range(0.5f, 0.9f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(EnemyLaserFireTime);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    DestroyEnemy();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your shooting methods at any moment.

following your game logic you need to call `BecomeVisible();`.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
  BecomeVisible();
}
```